# How to load style.css root directory in WordPress page.php, single.php in contents

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am making a WordPress theme. But I have a problem. style.css stylesheet is not loading in page.php contents. When I edit a post in wp editor and add `<div class=w3-red"> <button class="w3-btn w3-red">` and more related codes. When I published a post, they are not showing on front-end. I think WordPress doesn't support the page style customization option with wp editor. I have also added my own style.css in header.php.

I am using w3.css stylesheet in my web root directory. style.css

```
<div class="w3-card w3-red"> Hello </div>
```

This code in not loading in frontend.

Comment: Please help me now

Comment: HTML code must be enclosed with backticks, otherwise it's invisible: `

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this link](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/custom-css-wordpress/?rad=b&utm_expid=3606929-86.PHoDXYJeQYmWFQIujGOFZg.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F)

or

Just put your stylesheets (style.css) in a directory `wp-content\themes\[YOUR_THEME]\css\`.
Then you can link stylesheet through simply put below code (theme header.php file).

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style.css when you creating a theme it must be in on the same folder as your index.php

in your head load the style using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();?>/style.css">
```

if your stylesheet is on css folder load it using this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/folder/name.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is accessing image using css file location as the reference point, e.g.

.class-name{

background-image:url("../images/file-name"); //one level up, then images folder

background-image:url("../../images-directory-02/images/file-name"); //two levels up, then two folders in

}